# PowerExchange CDC 10.1 for Oracle installation

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, cdc, informatica-powerexchange, oracle-cdc

Can anyone provide step by step process to install PowerExchange CDC for Oracle, so that we can implement in our project?

Comment: Welcome to the community! Please explain the issue, describe in detail what you've done so far and where the problem is - this will help others trying to help you!

Comment: I am still researching what all need to be done to implement power exchange cdc for oracle.Currently we have Oracle source server(linux) and Power center 10.1(Linux) server. just want to establish power exchange installation and connection.  1) we ll install power exchange on oracle server with listener service and logger service 2) we ll install power exchange listener and logger service and powerexchange navigator in power center  server   3) set dbmover.cfg and pwxcll.cfg file in power center server. Do we need to create listener and logger services in admin console? is my approach correct?